# Добрый день. Есть ли у кого-то код ползунка на js, для навигации по частям одностраничного сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, range

```
   Ползунок для переключения на разные части сайта
```

Comment: Хотя бы пример можно какой-то? Просто как с помощью инпута с типом ренж? можно передвигаться по сайту?

Comment: Что вы именно имеете ввиду?

Comment: обычный вертикальный ползунок, который при изменении значения, скролит сайт до нужного раздела

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю правильно ли я вас понял или нет, но вот что я могу вам предложить

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu > a {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#test1">1</a>
  <a href="#test2">2</a>
  <a href="#test3">3</a>
  <a href="#test4">4</a>
  <a href="#test5">5</a>
  <a href="#test6">6</a>
</div>
<div id="test1" style="--color: green">1</div>
<div id="test2" style="--color: red">2</div>
<div id="test3" style="--color: blue">3</div>
<div id="test4" style="--color: royalblue">4</div>
<div id="test5" style="--color: orange">5</div>
<div id="test6" style="--color: yellow">6</div>
```